# Unable to install Web Developer Tools

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

No matter what I do, I am unable to get Web Developer Tools installed. I had Community Edition of Visual Studio 2015, but I did a clean installation of Enterprise afterwards (free key from school) after uninstalling 2015 CE using TotalUninstaller.

When I then try to install Web Essentials, it tells me I need to install Web Developer Tools. However, I did install it upon installing Visual Studio. I also tried to tick it off, uninstall Web Developer Tools, and then install it again afterwards. No luck at all.

I'm almost forced to do a complete reinstallation of Windows... What can I possibly do?

Comment: I have the same problem. Went through the uninstall and reinstall process. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Tony_Henrich Nope. Ended up going a different route as far as I remember.